# Rails ActiveRecord find through has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

iOS developer learning Rails here. Trying to query active record for records based on a `has_many` relation's property. Apologies if this is simple but I just can't figure it out. I've read about and have been trying to use `scope`, `.where`, `.joins`, but there are so many contradicting posts and blogs online I'm unsure which to use and what's correct...

On to the problem:

I have two ActiveRecord models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

and

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

An item has a property `title`, I am trying to find all of the `User`s that have an item with a `title` that is similar to some search parameter in string format.

I have managed to do such using a search for items and then `.map` like this:

```
users_owning_item_in_search_parameter = Item.where{ (title =~ my{@search_param + "%"}) }.map! { |i| i.user }
```

(that syntax comes from the [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.)

But that command returns an `Array` when I want an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, because I need to do some further filtering that requires this instance type.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why items `belongs_to :items` and not `belongs_to :users`?

Comment: Yep, that reason is... typo

Comment: `User.find_each { |user| user.items.find_by_title('your string') }` is a potential solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
User.joins(:items).where('items.title LIKE ?', "#{@search_param}%")
```

You'll have to modify it a bit if you want to take advantage of squeel.

Comment: well that's embarrassing for me! Thanks

Comment: Squeel if anyone wants to know:

`User.joins(:items).where{ items.title =~ my{param+ "%" }`